# Returning merged arrays from function in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct _item {
    int v, w;
} item;

void printItems(item *t, int n) {
int i;
    for(i= 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%4i",t[i].v);
    printf("\n");
}

item * newItemSet(int n) {
    int i;
    item *t = (item*)malloc(sizeof(item));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        (t+i)->v = rand()%100;
        (t+i)->w = rand()%100;
    }
    return t;
}

item * mer(item*a, int n, item*b, int m) {
    int size = m+n;
    item*q = (item*)malloc(sizeof(item)*size);
    int i, c;
    c = 0;
    printf("a----\n");
    printItems(a,n);
    printf("b----\n");
    printItems(b,m);
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        q[c] = a[i];
        c++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i<m; i++) {
        q[c] = b[i];
        c++;
    }
    printItems(q,size);
    return q;
}   


int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    item * a = newItemSet(6);
    item *b = newItemSet(6);
    item *c = mer(a,6,b,6);
    printItems(c,12);   
    return 0;
}
```

At every execution, the first part of `c` is correct, up to the last two elements of `b`. What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The allocation for `newItemSet` does not appear correct.  It should be:

```
item *t = malloc(sizeof(item) * n);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
item *t = (item*)malloc(sizeof(item));
```

Should be:

```
item *t = malloc(n * sizeof(item));
```

You are allocating space for `n` items, not one `item`. Also, there is no need to cast the return value of `malloc` and it can hide errors.